# Restoring differential backup creates DEFUNCT log file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, restore

Here is my problem.  I'm trying to move a database to a new server via a full restore, then cutover with a quick differential backup/restore.  I can do a full restore without a problem, but when restoring the differential backup, I get the following warning:

> Msg 3127, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The file 'Database_Log2' of
>   restored database 'DatabaseName' is being left in the
>   defunct state because the database is using the simple recovery model
>   and the file is marked for read-write access. Therefore, only
>   read-only files can be recovered by piecemeal restore.

The database restores and is considered online, but any backup operation fails due to this DEFUNCT file with the following error:

> Msg 3636, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 An error occurred while processing
>   'BackupMetadata' metadata for database id 10 file id 6. Msg 3046,
>   Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Inconsistent metadata has been encountered.
>   The only possible backup operation is a tail-log backup using the WITH
>   CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR or NO_TRUNCATE option. Msg 3013, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1 BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

If I do a RESTORE FILELISTONLY on the full and differential both give me the same output, which matches what I see from sys.database_files on the source database.  Server is SQL2012 SP1, on Developer edition.

I can do a full backup, and immediately afterward do a differential, and restore these files to a different database on the same server and see the exact same problem, so there is something with how the differential is created that is causing this.  If I restore the full backup WITH RECOVERY there is no problem.  I do not know if this file used to exist on this database, but it is entirely possible this file used to exist and was deleted a long time ago.  If I query sys.database_files on the restored database, the DEFUNCT file has a value for drop_lsn, which seems to confirm this.  Currently in the source database there is only one filegroup (PRIMARY), 4 data files and one log file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please show us the statements you're using to do the backups and restores?

Comment: Nothing out-of-the-ordinary.  RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName FROM DISK = 'D:\Full.bak' WITH REPLACE, NORECOVERY
Then RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName FROM DISK = 'D:\Diff.bak' WITH RECOVERY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the steps to reproduce this, tested on SQL 2012 SP1 Developer Edition.  This does not occur on SQL 2008.  To summarize, a database created in SQL 2012 while the model database is in SIMPLE recovery, that has a full backup taken while an extra log file exists, cannot create usable differential backups if that extra log file is ever deleted.

```
ALTER DATABASE [model] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
CREATE DATABASE [DefunctTest]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DefunctTest] ADD LOG FILE ( NAME = N'DefunctTest_log2', FILENAME = N'D:\DefunctTest_log2.ldf' , SIZE = 25600KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [DefunctTest] TO DISK = 'D:\DefunctTestPostLogFile.bak' WITH INIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DefunctTest]  REMOVE FILE [DefunctTest_log2]
GO

BACKUP DATABASE [DefunctTest] TO DISK = 'D:\DefunctTestFull.bak' WITH INIT
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [DefunctTest] TO DISK = 'D:\DefunctTestDiff.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL, INIT
GO
--Show that the backups only have the one log file.
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\DefunctTestFull.bak'
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\DefunctTestDiff.bak'
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [DefunctTest2] FROM DISK = 'D:\DefunctTestFull.bak' WITH 
MOVE 'DefunctTest' TO 'D:\DefunctTest2.mdf',
MOVE 'DefunctTest_log' TO 'D:\DefunctTest2_log.ldf', REPLACE, NORECOVERY
GO
--This restore will have the error.
RESTORE DATABASE [DefunctTest2] FROM DISK = 'D:\DefunctTestDiff.bak' WITH RECOVERY
GO

USE [DefunctTest2]
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
GO
```

I submitted a Connect item for this bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/860869/differential-restore-creates-defunct-log-file).  The only way I've been able to remove this defunct file is to detach the database, and re-attach with ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG.

UPDATE: The bug that creates this scenario in my repro script seems to have been fixed by this KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2830400.  From the comments it appears an additional fix is available for SQL2012/2014, the scenarios seem very similar:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3009576

Comment: I would include your script in the connect comments to help people reproduce.

Comment: I do not get any errors running your script on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, 11.0.3412 (CU9 for SP1)

Comment: The repro script is in the Connect item, if you click the Details button.

Comment: Shawn, looking through the fixes in the CU's, I think this one probably fixed this behavior: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830400

Comment: I had a battle with this last week and this thread help me sort it out so thank you. It looks like the fix is in SQL 2012 SP2 CU3: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3009576

Comment: FilamentUnities if the comment above is correct, please update your answer